# Connecting iphone with google appengine

Tags: objective-c, google-app-engine

I am trying build a database on google appengine and connect it to my IOS program. I am new in server side programming. I have done the tutorial about google appengine with java and eclipse since i know java and have no idea about Python. Can anyone direct me to a tutorial about this? All I found on the Internet is talking about Python and couldn't find anything about this topic with java and ObjectiveX.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#language  doesn't matter what your client uses. you have to use the languages that G.A.E supports for the server-side components.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with you will have to complete the [Getting Started: Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) tutorial that is written by Google App Engine team, to understand the basic concepts of working with such environment.

For your client side it doesn't really matter what you are using, it can be ObjectiveX or C# or SubjectiveY, as long as you can connect using whatever you built on the server side.

Comment: And once you've done this, check out Google Cloud Endpoints (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview) which can expose an API you access from an Objective-C app (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios).